# Counting parents types where all children are only of a particular type

Tags: sql, database, performance, psql

```
Project             Accomplishment
-------              ---------------
id                   id
project_name         accomplishment_name
project_status_id    project_id
                     accomplishment_status_id
```

A project can have many Accomplishments; an Accomplishment can only have 1 project.

I have a very basic query so far but I'm not very familiar with subqueries or the most efficient way to do this. I tried getting a count of all the accomplishments of a project by status and then trying to do math to figure out if status of 3 is equal to the total count of accomplishments but that feels super efficient.

Here's what I currently have:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, COUNT(a) AS active_accomp_count FROM habits4.accomplishment a
    join habits4.project p ON p.id = a.project_id
    WHERE a.accomp_status_id = 1
    GROUP BY p.id

SELECT p.id, p.name, count(a) AS completed_accomp_count FROM habits4.accomplishment a
    JOIN habits4.project p ON p.id = a.project_id
    WHERE a.accomp_status_id = 2
    GROUP BY p.id

SELECT p.id, p.name, COUNT(a) AS inactive_accomp_count FROM habits4.accomplishment a
        JOIN habits4.project p ON p.id = a.project_id
        WHERE a.accomp_status_id = 3
        GROUP BY p.id
```

I expect the output to show the Project_ID and Project_name for all projects that only have ALL of its associated Accomplishments status = 3.

Example Data:

```
Project 1                 Project 2
-----------------         -----------------
Accomplishment 1          Accomplishment 5
    status = 1                 status = 3

Accomplishment 2          Accomplishment 6
    status = 1                 status = 3

Accomplishment 3
    status = 2
```

Accomplishment 4
    status = 3
`

Project 2 should show in the output because it ONLY has Accomplishments with a status of 3.
Project 1 should NOT show in the output because, although it DOES have an Accomplishment with status = 3 it also has Accomplishments that have a status OTHER than 3.

Answer (score 1):

So you want the projects which meet two conditions.

1. Has at least one accomplishment with `status = 3`
2. Has no accomplishments with status other than 3.

The first one is easy with an inner join and a group by.
Combining the two conditions is straightforward.
So let's start with selecting all projects which do not have an accomplishment other than status = 3.

If we want the projects which have no accomplishments, we can do a left outer join and select the records with a NULL created from the outer join.

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, COUNT(a) AS inactive_accomp_count
FROM habits4.project p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN habits4.accomplishment a ON p.id = a.project_id
WHERE a.id IS NULL
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
```

Then combine it with the inner join we need for projects with accomplishments with status 3,

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, COUNT(a) AS inactive_accomp_count
FROM habits4.project p
    INNER JOIN habits4.accomplishment a ON p.id = a.project_id
WHERE a.accomp_status_id = 3
```

So together we have:

```
SELECT p.id AS inactive_accomp_count
FROM habits4.project p1
    INNER JOIN habits4.accomplishment a1 ON p1.id = a1.project_id
    INNER JOIN habits4.project p2 ON p1.id = p2.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN habits4.accomplishment a2 ON p2.id = a2.project_id
WHERE a2.id IS NULL
GROUP BY p1.id
```

This will give you the correct projects, but the counts will be messed up because we are doing too much in the group of records.  So use this as a sub-select, and write the outer query to count the records correctly.

Comment: That's exactly it! Not sure why I was spacing inner joins -.-
Thanks for your help!